# SAPUI5 add customData to xmlView

Tags: view, sapui5

I would like to transfer javascript generated view to an xmlView.

This works great and I can add it to the shell:

```
var headItem = new sap.ui.unified.ShellHeadItem({
        icon: "sap-icon://upload-to-cloud",
        id: "network-icon",
        customData: [
            new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
                key: "color",
                value: "{= ${appValues>/isOnline} ? 'is-online' : 'is-offline' }",
                writeToDom: true
            })
        ]
});
```

What do I need to do to add this to an XML View:

```
<u:ShellHeadItem
    id="network-icon"
    icon="sap-icon://upload-to-cloud"
    tooltip="Network status"/>
```

I tried to add it in the viewController, but it does not update the DOM.

```
onInit: function() {
    var oNetworkIcon = this.getView().byId("network-icon");

    oNetworkIcon.setModel(sap.ui.getCore().getModel("appValues"));
    oNetworkIcon.addCustomData(new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
           key: "color",
           value: "{= ${/isOnline} ? 'is-online' : 'is-offline' }",
           writeToDom: true
    }));
    //if you happen to know how to add a class
    oNetworkIcon.addStyleClass("blub"); 
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<u:ShellHeadItem
        id="network-icon"
        icon="sap-icon://upload-to-cloud"
        tooltip="Network status">
    <u:customData>
        <core:CustomData key="color" value="{= ${/isOnline} ? 'is-online' : 'is-offline' }" writeToDom="true" />
    </u:customData>
</u:ShellHeadItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that the OP is asking for a way to write the data into the DOM.
But for those who need to access the extra data of a control through JS only:
This method is more streamlined and easier to read:

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:customData="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
  xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified">
  <unified:ShellHeadItem id="network-icon"
    icon="sap-icon://upload-to-cloud"
    tooltip="Network status"
    customData:color="{= ${/isOnline} ? 'is-online' : 'is-offline' }" />
</mvc:View>
```

You can access this extra data like so:

```js
var myData = this.byId("network-icon").data("color");
```

---

Documentation: [Custom Data - Attaching Data Objects to Controls](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) (See "Use in XML Views").